# Aborting transaction created by @Transactional but returning properly (not throwing exception)

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, transactions

I have a method annotated with @Transactional. In this method a data object is parsed and should finally be saved in the database. If the parsing fails, this method does not throw an exception, but returns with a special value.

How can I tell the transaction to rollback? Normally the transactions created by @Transactional just rollback on exception.

Please don't tell me why I should not return a special value or why using @Transactional does not make sense in my case. I need an effective solution, even if its not the nicest design - I know it by myself.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [TransactionAspectSuport.currentTransactionStatus()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.html#currentTransactionStatus%28%29).[setRollbackOnly()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionStatus.html#setRollbackOnly%28%29).